# How to setup Authentication with ApiGility

Tags: laminas-api-tools

I am attempting to setup Authentication with ApiGility.

I have added a Login route, and when I access this route with no authentication in place I am expecting to receive:

```
{
"type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
"title": "Forbidden",
"status": 403,
"detail": "Forbidden"
}
```

As I do on my other ApiGility app.

However when I attempt to access the end point it is readily available despite having set Authentication.

Is there something that can affect this?

Here are some screenshots of my settings:

**End point for login:**

[image]

**Fields**

[image]

**Authorized methods**

[image]

**Login Method - just returns true for now**
[image]

**Authentication setup**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I updated ApiGility via composer and it started to work.